# Pulling username from Database

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2013

I'm setting up a login page for a program I'm making for a Uni Degree.

The login page itself works, but I'm having an issue with something else.

The login page itself is just a passcode.
Numeric characters in a text box get verified through an access database.

I set up my own subroutine (LoginProcedure) with the following code:

```
SELECT        COUNT(*) AS Result, [Password] AS Pass, Username AS [User]
FROM            users
GROUP BY [Password], Username
HAVING        (COUNT(*) = 1) AND ([Password] = ?)
```

And on the login button, have the following code:

```
Dim login = UsersTableAdapter.LoginProcedure(txtPass.Text)
        If login Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Passcode Not Recognised!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Else
            Till.Show()
        End If
```

So if the Text in txtPass matches any of the passwords in the Database, the Till form opens, otherwise they receive an error.

However, I also have a text box which I want a Username to appear in. 
Is there anyway for the Username to automatically fill in, from the password provided??

PS. 
It's VB2013... Uni has old software.

Comment: what is that textbox name ?

Comment: Are you sure you thought this through?  What if more than one person have the same password?

Comment: What if two users have the same password?

Comment: It's only a Uni thing, this software won't see the light of day, so I don't need to put too much thought into it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not requiring a username on login? Usually you would take the username and find that in the database, and then you would compare the encrypted password to the stored encrypted password you have in the database.

If you want to stay with your current system you should just be able to select the username from the same index.

Comment: No, it's more like a passcode system. So each user has their own passcode, and they just enter the code to log in.

Comment: I don't know if something like this is feasible for a passcode system. Right now you're finding the username by their passcode, but are you ensuring that users can't have the same passcode? You might be better off having the user give you some other sort of login and then storing the passcode alongside it.

Comment: It's not a real system though, I just need a bit of code to get it working. I just need a name so that it appears through the rest of the program. I have an invisible textbox for the username, and then other labels on the rest of the program pull their name from that.

Comment: @JaySan is right, what happens, when two passcodes collide. Showing any sort of notification is breaching security. To avoid it, you the system should be giving them. This hurts usability, however.

Comment: Then I'd go with geeFlo's answer if that works for it. Although I would advise that you look at all of your programs as if they'll be used in the real world. It makes it easier to get into a professional mindset when the programs will be used in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

Weird setup, but I'm not judging.  To answer your question...

DLOOKUP the UserName from the User table (use your passcode as the criteria).

Either put the DLOOKUP formaula in the textbox, or assign the DLOOKUP result to the textbox on whatever action (opening the till form, or after your passcode is entered) you want to trigger it.

Comment: I've never heard of DLOOKUP on VBA. There's nothing on intellisense either. How does it work??

Comment: Sorry thought you were using Access as it was tagged.

Comment: Or since you're using SQL:  `"SELECT username FROM users WHERE Password = '" & txtPass.text) & "'"`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it's an Access DB linked to VB. I found some code similar to that
Dim str As String---
            str = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE (Password = '" & txtPass.Text & "')"---
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)---
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()---
            While dr.Read()---
                txtUser.Text = dr("Username").ToString---
            End While---

Except I get an error on dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Comment: If you're using Access, then use the DLOOKUP.   Assign it to the text box. `=dlookup("UserName", "Users", "Password = '" & txtPass.text & "'")`

Comment: The Database is in Access, but all the code is in VB. I'm making the program in VBStudio2013. My error keeps stating that my connection isn't open, but it is. And if I put in code to open the connection, it says it can't find the file, even though the path leads straight to the file....